# psql: change commandline editing mode?

Tags: psql

`psql`, the PostgreSQL CLI, uses readline for it's user interface. Readline allows both emacs- and vi editing mode, and `psql` uses emacs mode by default. I, on the other hand, use vi for everything; is there a command for setting vi editing mode in psql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to configure readline appropriately. Create a file `.inputrc` in your home directory with the following content:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Comment: This is obiously the answer! Thx